# Angular Directive to compare 2 dates from datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

i wrote this directive to compare 2 dates. these dates are inserted by a datetimepicker.

```js
angular.module('core').directive('greaterThan', [
    function () {

        var link = function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {

            var validate = function (viewValue) {

                var comparisonModel = $attrs.greaterThan;

                if (typeof viewValue === 'undefined' && !comparisonModel) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('greaterThan', true);
                }

                if (typeof viewValue === 'object' && !comparisonModel) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('greaterThan', Date.now() < viewValue.getTime());
                }

                if (typeof viewValue === 'object' && comparisonModel) {
                    // Format: "2015-09-15T07:00:00.000Z"
                    var dateTime = comparisonModel.replace(/"/g, '');
                    var myDate = new Date(Date.parse(dateTime));         
                    ctrl.$setValidity('greaterThan', myDate.getTime() < viewValue.getTime());
                }

            return viewValue;
        };

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validate);

        $attrs.$observe('greaterThan', function (comparisonModel) {
            return validate(ctrl.$viewValue);
        });

     };

     return {
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: link
    };

}]);
```

now i have 2 questions: 
1. is my style of code okay? what could i improve?
2. how can i write a test unit for this directive? for example: i don´t know how to insert values to this directive.